# Cloudflare R2:The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your secret access key and signing method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cloudflare

i need some help with the following problem.

When i do

`await s3.getSignedUrlPromise('putObject', { Bucket: 'aya-app', Key: 'dog.png', Expires: 3600 })`

Response:

`SignatureDoesNotMatch`
The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your secret access key and signing method.

But when i do

```js
await s3.getSignedUrlPromise('listBuckets', {})
```

The response is  the answer is satisfactory

```xml
<ListBucketResult xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<Name>aya-app</Name>
<IsTruncated>false</IsTruncated>
<MaxKeys>1000</MaxKeys>
<KeyCount>0</KeyCount>
</ListBucketResult>
```

I already checked:

- Access key id
- SecreteAccesKey.
- I tried with 'signature:v2 /v3/v4'

My complete code below:

````js
import S3 from 'aws-sdk/clients/s3.js';

const s3 = new S3({
    endpoint: `https://xxxxxxxxxx.r2.cloudflarestorage.com/aya-app`,
    accessKeyId: "xxxxxxx",
    secretAccessKey: "xxxxxxx",
    signatureVersion: 'v4',
    region: 'auto',
    version: '2006-03-01',
});

async function testR2() {
    let listBuckets = await s3.getSignedUrlPromise('listBuckets', {})         

    let putObject = await s3.getSignedUrlPromise('putObject', { Bucket: 'aya-app', Key: 'dog.png', Expires: 3600 })

    console.log("listBuckets", listBuckets, "putObject", putObject)
}

await testR2()```
````

Comment: disable all encryption and signing in the request, fixed it for me in the C# SDK